How do I find my Ethereum I bought in 2018... I think I took it offline at the time. I have the address I seem to have transferred it to
Total crypto dummie here.
I bought some Ethereum in 2018, and remember using MetaMask to try and take it offline. I haven't the faintest idea what I did after it went to MetaMask...but this is the transaction I made which still has the coin in it- 0x42a70a990c846b29BFDB32fFceE41e673136c70D
I've lost the passcode it gave me at the time.
I have a phrase here which may be the mnemonic phrase I need but I haven't a clue where to input it to try and get it back online?
I used coinbase and binance as well.
Any help appreciated, as am way out of my depth! thank you

Thank you so much. I suspect the seed phrase I have is actually for MetaMask- but I took the coin off MetaMask … and have lost the code I was given. I do have something that starts with UTC and a time code & then the number for the wallet that I can see on the blockchain contains s my coin. Is that anything?! As you can tell I am so out of my depth & have no idea what I’m doing!! Appreciate the advice….

If you have the seed phrase, then you can just install metamask and recover your old wallet using that phrase.
